# jerky mouse control while running .jnlp file

Tags: 12.04, mouse

I am having problems whenever I try to run a .jnlp file. I am having no problems launching the game, but once in it, the mouse control is very jerky and trying to use it is very frustrating. I have tried opening these java files in Java 6 and Java 7 with the same results. I don't have any mouse control issues in any other applications. Any help would be great. I am running ubuntu 12.04 lts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found an answer to my lag problem when running .jnlp files.  I installed the gnome classic desktop and now the files run fine. Obviously, it was a memory problem.